# Identifier is too long issue in Oracle 12.2

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle12c

I heard that from 12.2 Oracle started supporting longer identifiers (i.e., up to 128 characters). But the following statement is still throwing *ORA-00972: identifier is too long* error at line number 2!!. I meant I can define user name with >30 characters but not the password.

```
CREATE USER xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
IDENTIFIED BY xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, CREATE SYNONYM, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
```

**Note:** My database version is Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 and I have also ensured that the compatibility of my database is 12.2.0

Comment: Check the max_string_size database parameter - that needs to be set to EXTENDED to take advantage of the long identifiers. See [Tim Hall's article on the subject](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1#12cr2-update) for more information.

Comment: @Boneist - I am able to create user with length >30 characters but not password. Hence I don't think it is anything to do with max_string_size.

Comment: There isn't a default password policy in place that's restricting the length of the password, is there?

Comment: I didn't set anything explicitly. I am just trying it on a brand new installation of Oracle 12C.2

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-AA1AA635-1CD5-422E-B8CA-681ED7C253CA

"Passwords can be at most 30 bytes long."